# Does the JBoss embeddable/modular server still exists?

Tags: jboss, ejb-3.0, embeddable

While following along some examples about EJB 3.0 given in the book "Java Persistence with Hibernate" from 2007 I was told to

Go to http://jboss.com/products/ejb3, download the modular embeddable
server

But all I can see there, is a plugin called "JBoss EJB3 Plugin 1.0.19" that contains some jar's. So I'm not sure whether the instructions from 2007 may not be outdated by now, since this plugin is obviously not a server

Basically I guess what I need is some sort of a lightweight embeddable Jboss container. Can you please point me into the right direction? Or should I just go for the standard JBoss AS 6.0 release?

The example itself is about a simply HelloWorld program that takes a string message and writes it out to the database using EJB 3.0, nothing fancy, I'm still a beginner.

thx

Never mind: for the sake of future reference: to find some of the answers visit

https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=972608&start=0

Answer (score 0):

[Answer from Christian on hibernate forum:](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2355012&sid=a6d9f47f2c35027867e90b5ebcd23f87#p2355012)

> Since the book has been released, the "JBoss embeddable EJB3 server"
>   as described and used in the book has been deprecated. What is now
>   available, "Embeddable JBoss application server", is not the same
>   (although it looks similar at first).
>
> You have two choices:
>
> 1. Follow the book to the letter and download the old server, it is included in the CaveatEmptor/HelloWorld download (with all libs etc.)
>      on http://caveatemptor.hibernate.org
> 2. Drop that section of the book after reading it once and get started with the examples that come with the newer embeddable JBoss AS.